# ASP.net Access Controller Variable in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Ok, I have a controller that returns a response to an ajax call and I'd like to intercept that response in my view. How can I do this?

Alternatively, how could i reference my ajax variable in my view?

View: ContractorList.ascx
Controller: HaulerController.cs

Comment: How are you planning to intercept this? The view itself just renders HTML which is sent to the browser. An AJAX call allows the browser to update this rendered HTML on the client itself.

Comment: Well how can I access an AJAX variable in HTML

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're asking, but I think the answer is something along the lines of this:

```
$.get("/url/to/action", {/* data you're passing to action */}, function (response) {

    // your result is available here.... 
    // you want to pass it into the callback method as an argument, as above
    // everything your action returns to the page is stored in the response object.

    // can you do something like:
        var idx = response.indexOf('specific string I expect');
        if (idx > -1)
            // the string you expected is there so show popup....

    }, "html");

    return false;
});
```

If this isn't what you're after, please clarify

Comment: yes I want to access whats in the response object in my view because depending on the value of that response object I want to show a pop up box.

Comment: are you returning HTML or JSON to the page?

Comment: Sorry I'm a totally newbie perhaps this will clarify your Question.

Comment: <!--- HTML VIEW HERE -->
I create the objects on my Page etc my dispaly
<!-- END HTML VIEW HERE -->

<Script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Hauler/CreateContractor",
        dataType: "text",
        data: querystring,
        success: function(result) {
            load();
        }
    });
<!----END SCRIPT -->

Now i want to check that result variable in my HTML above how can i do that?

Comment: then you're probably returning HTML, so you can't inspect the response as an object the way you could if it was JSON. But you do have options. I'll update the answer with a suggestion

Comment: btw - change the dataType to "html" rather than "text".. jQuery's smart enough to know what to do with "html", but it won't do anything with text

Comment: Changed to html but i only know how to make a click event pop up. How can I modify this code to use it in the space you showed me.

Comment: <div id='ContractorPopUp' class="white_content" style="height:25%;top:0%";>
            <p>Contractor was successfully added.</p>
            <p>Contractor already exists and has been added to your list of contractors. Please enter a unique email when creating a new contractor.</p>
            <input type='submit' style="margin-top:10px" type="button" class="inputButton" value='Close' onClick='document.getElementById("ContractorPopUp").style.display = "none"'>

Comment: if it's a click event you need, something like this might work:

`$('#idOfElementToClick').trigger("click")`